# Docker compose for java backend and python frontend application

Tags: java, python, docker, docker-compose

I have simple spring boot java backend application which get element from the list (endpoint `/get/{id}`) and add element to the list (endpoint `/add/{product}`):

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    List<String> products = Arrays.asList("test");

    @PostMapping(path="/add/{product}")
    public int addProduct(@PathVariable final String product){
        products.add(product);
        return products.size()-1;
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/get/{id}")
    public String getValue(@PathVariable final int id){
        return products.get(id);
    }
}
```

I created Dockerfile for this like:

```
FROM openjdk:11

# copy the packaged jar file into our docker image
COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /demo.jar

EXPOSE 8080/tcp

# set the startup command to execute the jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/demo.jar"]
```

Now I can build image (`docker build -t java_backend .`) and run application (`docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 java_backend`).

Thus, under `localhost:8080/get/0` I got `"test"`, under `localhost:8080/add/something` I can add element. Everything is fine.

As frontend I have simple python application like:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests as r
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def renderProduct():
    return """
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>""" + os.environ["title"] + """</title>
                </head>    
                <form id="1" method="POST">
                    <input name="getID"/>
                    <br>
                    <input name="addID">
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
                </html>
                """

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def queryAndRender():
    builded = "<html>"
    if request.form["getID"] is not None:
        resp = r.get("http://localhost:8080/get/" + request.form["getID"])
        builded = builded + "PRODUCT:" + resp.text + "<br>"

    if request.form["addID"] is not None:
        resp = r.get("http://localhost:8080/add/" + request.form["addID"])
        builded = builded + "ADDED ID:" + resp.text + "<br>"

    builded = builded + """<html>
                            <head>
                                <title>""" + os.environ["title"] + """</title>
                            </head>
                            <form id="1" method="POST">
                                <input name="getID"/>
                                <br>
                                <input name="addID">
                                <input type="submit">
                            </form>
                            </html>
                            """

    return builded;


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And Dockerfile:

```
ARG version=3.8.5-alpine3.11
FROM python:${version}

ENV title="Hello world"
ENV test testspacja
ENV FLASK_APP=/main.py

RUN pip install Flask==1.1.2
RUN pip install requests==2.22.0

COPY main.py /
RUN sed -i 's/localhost:8080/backend/g' /main.py

EXPOSE 80/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["flask", "run"]
CMD ["-h", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "80"]
```

At the end I created `docker-compose.yml` file to run both of them:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
        backend:
                image: java_backend
                ports:
                         - "8080:8080"

        frontend:
                image: frontend
                ports:
                        - "8081:80"
```

Now I try to start `docker-compose up --build backend frontend`.

Frontend and backend are working independent, hence if I try put `localhost:8080/get/0` I am getting `"test"`, If I go to `localhost:8081` I see my frontend. But if I put some values in textboxes and click submit then I got 500 Internal Server Error. So services are not connected. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: You'd need to look at the container logs to see why there's a 500 error.  If the backend application is listening on port 8080 and not port 80 (inside the container, `ports:` don't matter here) you'll get a failure connecting.  It'd be better to use an environment variable like `os.environ['BACKEND_URL']` than to try to modify the source code with `sed` at image build time.

Comment: So in line `resp = r.get("http://localhost:8080/get/" + request.form["getID"])` I should put `os.environ['BACKEND_URL']` in place of `"http://localhost:8080"` so I will have:
`resp = r.get(os.environ['BACKEND_URL'] + "/get/" + request.form["getID"])`
where on my local machine `BACKEND_URL=htp://localhost:8080`. Am I right?

Comment: That seems right, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are accidentally erasing the backend port. Try replacing

```
RUN sed -i 's/localhost:8080/backend/g' /main.py
```

with

```
RUN sed -i 's/localhost:8080/backend:8080/g' /main.py
```

Comment: I dont know.understand why it works now. Could you please explain maybe?

Comment: @milko With the previous version you have replaced all `localhost:8080` with `backend`, removing port number from the endpoint URL. The app tried to connect to the backend on the default port 80. but the backend listens on 8080.

Comment: Thats clear. We can say that `RUN sed -i 's/localhost:8080/backend/g' /main.py` is equal to `RUN sed -i 's/localhost:8080/backend:80/g' /main.py`

Answer (score 0):

I have one additional question for this. Let's suppose that I would like start frontend from container but backend only from the my local IDE (IntelliJ).

Of course line `RUN sed -i 's/localhost:8080/backend/g' /main.py` is commented so frontent is calling endpoints under `http://localhost:8080`.

In this case frontend is under `http://localhost:8081` and backend under `http://localhost:8080` (two endpoints - `/get/{id}` and `/add/{product}`). But why frontend which is running in container doesn't "see" my backend?